# Leetcode question Check Knight Tour Configuration

Tags: java

I was attempting some leetcode questions and I think I had (not the greatest) solution for a problem.  But when submitting it I'm getting 1024/1026 cases passed.  I manually did the case that gave me the wrong problem and I think theres an error with leetcode unless im missing something

```
import java.lang.Math;

class Solution {
    public boolean checkValidGrid(int[][] grid) {
        int index = 0;
        int length = grid.length;
        int[][] board = new int[length][length];

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < length; j++){
                board[i][j] = index;
                index++;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < length; j++){
                if(i == length - 1 && j == length - 1) break;
                int[] StartingLocation = FindLocation(board[i][j], grid);
                int[] EndingLocation = FindLocation(board[i][j] + 1, grid);

                boolean test = ValidDesination(StartingLocation,EndingLocation,board);
                if(test == false) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean ValidDesination(int[] startingLocation, int[] endingLocation, int[][] board){
        try{if(board[startingLocation[0] - 2][startingLocation[1] + 1] == board[endingLocation[0]][endingLocation[1]]) return true;}catch(Exception e){}
        try{if(board[startingLocation[0] - 2][startingLocation[1] - 1] == board[endingLocation[0]][endingLocation[1]]) return true;}catch(Exception e){}

        try{if(board[startingLocation[0] + 2][startingLocation[1] + 1] == board[endingLocation[0]][endingLocation[1]]) return true;}catch(Exception e){}
        try{if(board[startingLocation[0] + 2][startingLocation[1] - 1] == board[endingLocation[0]][endingLocation[1]]) return true;}catch(Exception e){}
        
        try{if(board[startingLocation[0] - 1][startingLocation[1] + 2] == board[endingLocation[0]][endingLocation[1]]) return true;}catch(Exception e){}
        try{if(board[startingLocation[0] - 1][startingLocation[1] - 2] == board[endingLocation[0]][endingLocation[1]]) return true;}catch(Exception e){}
        
        try{if(board[startingLocation[0] + 1][startingLocation[1] + 2] == board[endingLocation[0]][endingLocation[1]]) return true;}catch(Exception e){}
        try{if(board[startingLocation[0] + 1][startingLocation[1] - 2] == board[endingLocation[0]][endingLocation[1]]) return true;}catch(Exception e){}

        return false;
    }

    public int[] FindLocation(int n, int[][] grid){
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++){
                if(n == grid[i][j]) return new int[] {i,j};
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

[image]

That case is giving me the wrong answer, but when I did it by hand my answer was the correct one.  I just want to understand what I'm missing here.

Comment: without the problem description, we can hardly know if the result is correct or not - and checking if we got the same result as you running that code is not really helpful.  Please add the description to the question and including a [mre] also helps

Comment: Please add a link to the leetcode question.